# fsolve Python function, increment bug

Tags: python, scipy, system

I am trying to solve a four nonlinear equation system using the `scipy.optimize` function `fsolve`.

```
def equations(p):
   e1, e2, F, B = p

   Eq_F1 = (-F + Fa(4, e1, e2) + Fa(5,e1, e2) - A1*Acc1(e1, e2))
   Eq_T1 = (F*L + Fa(4,e1, e2)*A2 + Fa(5, e1, e2)*A3
   Eq_F2 = (Fb(1, e1, B)*A4*math.cos(B) + Fb(2,e1)*A5 + Fb(3,e1)*A6 + F*np.cos(alpha(e1, e2))- A7*Acc2)
   Eq_T2 = (Fb(1,e1, B)*math.cos(B)*A8- F*np.cos(alpha(e1, e2))*A9- Fb(2,e1)*A10- Fb(3,e1)*A11

   return (Eq_F1, Eq_T1, Eq_F2, Eq_T2)
```

Where `Fa`, `Fb` et `alpha` are functions of `e1`, `e2` and of a number.
`Ai` are constants I introduced to give you a global vision of the system.
I solve the system as following:

```
e1, e2, F, B  = fsolve(equations,(0.3,5,100,0.1), xtol=1.49012e-14)
```

Where the first guessing is reasonable knowing my problem.

The results given being false, I introduced `print(e1, e2, F, B)` in the equations function. What a surprise ! 
If the first values are `0.3, 5, 100, 0.1`, they immediately jump to extreme values on the second one, impeding the convergence... Thus the results turn far from relevant.

Has anyone got an idea ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: An idea: try to find better initial guess that does not diverge on first iteration using some kind of search.  Perhaps stop iteration after 1st round to speed search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your code because I don't have all the constants. Without knowing the exact details of your problem, I cannot be sure, but I will guess there is a high probability of a **numerical issue here**.

`fsolve` is a function that implements an algorithm in **numerical analysis**, and it iterates towards an approximate solution. Numerical algorithms can be "touchy" in the sense that if the user does not use the right settings for a particular problem, or if the particular choice of algorithm is unsuited for the problem, errors can result.

- Your starting point might be bad -- numerical algorithms can be very sensitive to the choice of starting point.
- Your xtol might be way too small -- this can lead to tiny step sizes in the iteration of the algorithm which prevents convergence and also causes numerical error (e.g. rounding error) to accumulate.

Comment: Thanks, I will give more information on Monday. Have a great week end !